# How to add borders between images in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am sticking together two plots using imshow, but I am trying to add a border in between the images and can't find a way to do it.

The code I am currently using is:

```
x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
a1 = X**2+Y**2
a2 = X**2+Y**2
a3 = X**2+Y**2
a = np.concatenate((a1,a2,a3), axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(a, cmap=cm.RdYlGn, aspect = 'auto')
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following image:
[image: output image]

However I would like two 'border' lines to be drawn to separate the images (i.e. between the first and the second and the second and third). How can I achieve this?

Comment: `plt.axvline(a1.shape[1]); plt.axvline(a1.shape[1]+a2.shape[1])`.  `axvline(x-pos)` draws a vertical line, default from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [plt.vlines](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) to draw vertical lines:

```
# collect coordinates from array shapes:
a1h, a1w = a1.shape
a2h, a2w = a2.shape

plt.vlines((a1w,a1w+a2w), (0,0), (a1h, a2h))

plt.ylim(50,0)
```